# Servlet receives a parameter sent by Android client as null

Tags: java, android, servlets

My problem is very simple. I am using a `HttpURLConnection` in an Android application to communicate with the server. 
Following is my Android client code:

```
public void post() {
        URL url = new URL("http://" + MainActivity.SERVER_IP + "/gov/RegisterServlet");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        try {
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            Uri.Builder queryBuilder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("token", token)
                    .appendQueryParameter("is_registered", "true");
            String s = queryBuilder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            OutputStreamWriter stream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            stream.write(s);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuffer responce = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                responce.append(line);
                responce.append('\r');
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, responce.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

`token` is a `String` I have initialized before.
Following is my basic Servlet class:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String token = req.getParameter("token");
        RequestDispatcher d = req.getRequestDispatcher("\\" + token);
        d.forward(req, resp);
    }
```

But unfortunately the `token` I receive at the servlet is always null. My question is why it becomes null, and are there any other better solution for what I am trying to achieve.

Thank you

Comment: Trace the packet to see if the value is really sent out

Comment: Try to debug/log what `s` looks like before sending it to the server; also try to debug/log what you got in `HttpServletRequest` on the server side.